# Generating an array of objects for insertMany in mongoose with express and node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm new to the dev and express community. I'm building a cafe review app as a pet project. I'm using the express framework mongoDB with mongoose. I am able to save a single object to a document, but when it comes to saving multiple objects I can't seem to figure it out. I keep getting a validation error of **Cafe validation failed: name: Cast to String failed for value "[ 'Cafe X', 'Cafe Y' ]" at path "name"** for all the key's. I then tried the insertMany function, but then I get an error message **cafe.insertMany is not a function**. I think I have to insert the cafe's as an array of objects, but how to I get it into an array of objects? Can someone maybe point me in the right direction?

The schema is defined as follows in the cafe.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const cafeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  chef: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 32,
    trim: true
  },
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  contactNumber: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cafe', cafeSchema);
```

The routes file is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const cafeController = require('../controllers/cafeController');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', cafeController.addCafeGet);
router.post('/', cafeController.addCafePost);

module.exports = router;
```

The cafeController is as follows, which works fine for a single object:

```
const Cafe = require('../models/cafe');

exports.addCafeGet = (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Add Restourant' });
};

exports.addCafePost = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const cafe = new Cafe(req.body);
    await cafe.save();
    res.json(cafe);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

In the html the user/admin adds the cafe's. At a later stage they will be able to add more cafe's simultaneously, for the example I only have two.

```
    form(action="", method="post")
      ul
        li
          input(type="text" name='name' placeholder='name')
        li
          input(type="text" name='city' placeholder='City')
        li
          input(type="text" name='chef' placeholder='Chef')
        li
          select#rating(name="rating")
            option(value="1") 1
            option(value="2") 2
            option(value="3") 3
            option(value="4") 4
            option(value="5") 5
        li
          input(type="text" name='contactNumber' placeholder='Contact number')
      ul
        li
          input(type="text" name='name' placeholder='name')
        li
          input(type="text" name='city' placeholder='City')
        li
          input(type="text" name='chef' placeholder='Chef')
        li
          select#rating(name="rating")
            option(value="1") 1
            option(value="2") 2
            option(value="3") 3
            option(value="4") 4
            option(value="5") 5
        li
          input(type="text" name='contactNumber' placeholder='Contact number')
        button(type="submit") SAVE
```

I'm planning to use a frontend framework at a later stage as well, but not right now.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other issues in what you trying to achieve, but check `res.json(restourant)`. What is `restourant` referring to?

Something like this could work in this instance:

```
// cafeController
exports.addRestourantPost = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const cafe = new Cafe(req.body);
    const savedCafe = await cafe.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedCafe.toJSON());
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the info. The reference to restourant should actually be cafe. I made a mistake posting the question. Changing the cafe controller doesn't help with the underlining issue of not being able to push two objects to the db. The error: **Cafe validation failed: name: Cast to String failed for value "[ 'Cafe X', 'Cafe Y' ]" at path "name", city: Cast to String failed for value "[ 'City X', 'City Y' ]" at path "city"**, etc. It could be an issue with getting the objects into the correct format, but I'm not sure. I need to be able to push multiple objects simultaneously to the db.

Comment: Ok, I'm sure there are many ways to approach this, but I would probably start with the HTML. Maybe it could be created dynamically with an 'add cafe' button that opens the next form. This way you can link a function to the button that creates a cafe object and adds it to an array.  Then, when the 'submit' button is clicked, another function loops through this array of cafes and posts each of them individually.